# quiero obtener un valor de un objeto q se encuentra en un array dentro de otro array en javascript

Tags: javascript

> *tengo una funcion q me devuelve un array con un objeto y dps arrays con objetos adentro..yo necesito poder acceder a los precios de los
> productos,el del objeto solo lo consigo, pero los q estan dentro de
> arrays no puedo obtenerlos... ayudaaa. quisiera guardar esos valores
> en una variable. gracias!*

```
productos = [{ id: 1, nombre: 'estrella', precio: 1200 },
 [{ id: 2, nombre: 'pesebre', precio: 1800 }],
 [{ id: 3, nombre: 'toalla', precio: 2800 }],
]
```

Comment: Prueba esto: `console.log(productos[0]['precio']); console.log(productos[1][0]['precio']); console.log(productos[2][0]['precio'])`

Comment: eso me muestra los valores q necesito! gracias! habria alguna forma de q me arme un array  "precios" sin hacerlo uno a uno?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu intención es sólo obtener los datos de los arrays internos puedes intentar usando:

```
let pesebreObj = productos[1][0];
let toallaObj = productos[2][0];
```

De esta manera las variables pesebreObj y toallaObj tendrían el objeto y podrías ver sus valores de la siguiente manera:

```
console.log(pesebreObj.precio); //Salida: 1800
```

Por otra parte, si tu intención es sacar los objetos que están dentro de los arrays internos para que sea más fácil llegar a estos valores debes usar la función flat:

```
productos = productos.flat();
```

De esta manera se eliminan los arrays internos y quedarías con sólo un array grande con tres objetos dentro.

```
console.log(productos[2].nombre); //Salida: toalla
```

Comment: excelente ! me contestaste justo lo q necesitaba! grande!!!!!gracias!

Comment: @PabloDiBiasi si la respuesta de Alejandro te sirvio, puedes marcarla como aceptada.